# Can I add SSH key to my machine that another user generated on their machine?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, windows, ssh-keygen

Another user and I are both using the same Ubuntu machine. They created an SSH key and disabled password authentification. Now I can no longer ssh into my user account on the Ubuntu machine. He saved what the out of the `ssh-keygen` command gave him. Is there a way I can use a screenshot image of this output (includes fingerprint and radomart image) to add the key to my windows machine, so I can log in to the Ubuntu machine again?

Comment: Can't he just re-enable password authentication just so you add your own key too?

Comment: No, you absolutely can't do that. They could give you their private key, with which you you could connect to _their_ account on the remote machine.

Comment: How would they give me their private key? That's not the same as the passphrase correct?

Comment: It's not the same. It's usually a file like `id_rsa` or `id_ed2551`. If they set up a passphrase on it, they should give you the passphrase too.

Answer (score 1):

If they have root access, then they can install a key for you: Create a new key pair, give them the public part (in a way that they know it is from you), ask them to install it in `~«your-user-name»/.ssh/authorized_keys`

However you can not re-create data from its hash (fingerprint and radomart image). Also this hash is just of the public key.

Or if this user saved a private key for you, and installed the public key on the server, then you can use it. 
But DON'T use this private key for any other purpose. It is save enough to access a server that they already have root access to.